# SQL to find runs of matching values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table called [Store_Sales] -

```
Store     Date     Sales
    1     23/04    10000
    2     23/04    11000
    1     22/04    10000
    2     22/04    10500
    1     21/04    10000
    2     21/04    10550
```

I want a SQL that will return a "run" of similar values in the Sales column for a particular store. For example, from the above table it would return store 1 for the 23rd, 22nd and 21st, as they all have the same value (10,000).

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Is what you are after a list of store ID, first date, last date and sales value where each date between first and last (inclusive) has the same sales value and there are no gaps in the date range and the date range is bigger than 1 day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at something like this (full example)

```
DECLARE @Store_Sales TABLE(
        Store INT,
        Date DATETIME,
        Sales FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Store_Sales SELECT 1,'23 Apr 2010',10000 
INSERT INTO @Store_Sales SELECT 2,'23 Apr 2010',11000 
INSERT INTO @Store_Sales SELECT 1,'22 Apr 2010',10000 
INSERT INTO @Store_Sales SELECT 2,'22 Apr 2010',10500 
INSERT INTO @Store_Sales SELECT 1,'21 Apr 2010',10000 
INSERT INTO @Store_Sales SELECT 2,'21 Apr 2010',10550 

SELECT  ss.Store,
        MIN(ss.Date) StartDate,
        MAX(ssNext.Date) EndDate,
        ss.Sales
FROM    @Store_Sales ss INNER JOIN
        @Store_Sales ssNext ON  ss.Store = ssNext.Store
                            AND ss.Date + 1 = ssNext.Date
                            AND ss.Sales = ssNext.Sales
GROUP BY    ss.Store,
            ss.Sales
```